# Questions on "can go so far"?

Tags: adverbs

Where should "only" be located? I have found examples of both possible locations in formal sources.

> Science can **only** go so far.

> Science can go **only** so far.

Comment: ***get*** is nearly always a bit "slangy" compared to alternatives. Probably *Science can **only do so much*** would be more likely than either of your suggestions, but syntactically they're all fine. It's a stylistic choice how to express the sentiment.

Comment: On this site, we're only allowed to ask one question at a time, even if it's about the same sentence. So, I've removed your question about "go" vs. "get". FF has already answered it in a comment, but if you'd still like it answered properly, feel free to ask about it in [another new question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 5):

Many English adverbs are quite flexible about their position within an utterance, and ***only*** is certainly no exception in this respect.

Strictly speaking, since ***only*** modifies ***so far*** (not ***go***), OP's second version is "more correct", because ***only*** should go as near as possible to the element it references. And until about 50 years ago, [both versions were equally common...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=can+only+ggoo+so+far%2Ccan+go+only+so+far&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

...but as you can see, things have changed quite a bit since then. If we're going to use emphatic ("intensifying / diminishing") ***only*** at all, we generally like to get it in *early*.

For example, we nearly always say *I only want a small portion*, when obviously what we *should* say is *I want only a small portion.* I don't *just **want*** it (not ***demand*** it) - I want *just a **small** portion* (not a ***large*** one).

Comment: I don't need to pass exams to prove I know English, and I have little patience with prescriptive grammarians telling me that some particularly common usage is in fact "incorrect". I wrote "strictly speaking" in my answer, but I don't care about such things myself. If you need to pass exams, ask your teacher.

Comment: Take note of the final paragraph in my answer. If you need to pass exams, you'll probably have to say/write *I **want only** a small portion*, despite the fact that the vast majority of native speakers will think that's a bit weird (since we almost *always* say *I **only want** [whatever relatively minor thing I'm asking for]*.

Comment: I disagree.  In the first example, 'only' modifies what science can do, ie 'go so far', not just 'go', consider the implicit '... - it can't go further'.  Whereas '... can go only so far' wants a comparison with something that can go further, eg 'Maths, however can go all the way'

Comment: @mcalex: That's certainly not how I see it. As stated, the word "only" functions as a "diminisher" (a sort of "inverse intensifier"). Consider how the assertions 1) *Science can **go** so far* and 2) *I can **borrow** £10* change when we include "only". It should be obvious that *strictly speaking*, since "only" doesn't modify the (highlighted) verb, it should come *after* the verb. I can treat the highlighted verb+complement of *I can only **borrow £10*** "as a unit" to give the relatively unlikely interpretation *All I could do was borrow £10* (I had no other course of action), but...

Comment: ... the corresponding transformation for OP's text gives *All science can do is **go so far***, which doesn't make sense to me in this context.

Comment: ...consider the implicit '... - it can't go further'. The distance it can go is *only **so far***, not ***further***. The verb *(**go**)* isn't directly relevant to the "diminisher" + "metaphorical distance" referent, which is effectively a self-contained semantic unit.

Answer (score 1):

1. Both are possible. The first sounds to me like something a native speaker would be more likely to say while the second would be used for emphasis, but maybe that depends on dialect, too, and the second is the default in some places - I'm not sure.
2. Pretty much. Science is limited in what it can do, either regarding what understanding it can provide, or what methods are available, or other goals - convincing your political opponent, or making a creative work, and so on. Look at context for what kind of limitations the speaker has in mind. (And for what they even mean by "science" - the method, the practice, the findings?)
3. No. Sounds weird. If anything, "science can only get you so far" sounds more natural than that, but not better than "science can only go so far", just a similar thing to say.